# SAMG55 - bootloader tools

Tags: atmel, bootloader

I'm trying to use the ROM bootloader on the SAMG55 as described in AT09002. The application note describes using a tool 'hex2fw.py'. Where can I get that and the config files it uses?

I found this thread - https://community.atmel.com/forum/entering-bootloader-atmel-samg55-xplained-pro - which has a modified version of the script, but no config files that it needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, I tracked down a copy of the zip file (20831 bytes) for [Atmel Application Note AT09002](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/Atmel-42305-SAM-I2C-SPI-Bootloader_ApplicationNote_AT09002.pdf) which was stored in the Wayback Machine (archive.org) on 1st August 2017:

[Atmel-42305-SAM-I2C-SPI-Bootloader_ApplicationNote_AT09002.zip](http://web.archive.org/web/20170801000000/http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-42305-SAM-I2C-SPI-Bootloader_ApplicationNote_AT09002.zip)

It contains the Python tool `hex2fy.py` and config files which you mentioned.

That's the latest version which I could find archived there.